# Does Call Of Duty: Black Ops from Direct2Drive require Steam?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops, version-differences

As the title says I cant seem to find any information about this , it does have a notice saying it requires 3rd party software but it doesn't say what.

The other reason I ask is because MW2 always required steam and there was no alternative and I dont want to buy it from steam again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does require Steam. The game doesn't run without it, even the retail version requires Steam.

How do I know? I bought it from Direct2Drive.

You can even enter the serial number you get from D2D into Steam ("Add A Game...") to get around the D2D download manager.